# object has no attribute - switch window - selenium python - pycharm

Tags: python, selenium, pycharm

```
driver.get("https://usawheelstires.com/")

driver.maximize_window()

driver.find_element(By.XPATH,("//input[@name='dealername']")).send_keys("Syed Hassan")

driver.find_element(By.XPATH,("//input[@name='dealerEmail']")).send_keys("syedhassan1230@gmail.com")

driver.find_element(By.XPATH, ("//input[@name='dealerPhone']")).send_keys("03070205196")

driver.find_element(By.XPATH, ("//input[@name='dealerState']")).send_keys("NY")

driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "dealerInputFieldsSubmit").click()

after_window = driver.window_handles[1]

driver.switch_to.window(after_window)

print(after_window)

driver.find_element(By.LINK_TEXT, "marketing.usawheel@gmail.com").click()
```

**The above code has an error** .

```
AttributeError: 'WebDriver' object has no attribute '_window_handles'. Did you mean: 'window_handles'?
```

Note: its not clicking on next page "NEXT" button which is appearing on the second page.

Answer (score 1):

From the error trace I see

> > 'WebDriver' object has no attribute '_window_handles'

Looks like in the code you have a typo.
It should be there

```py
after_window = driver.window_handles[1]
```

While looks like you wrote

```py
after_window = driver._window_handles[1]
```

Comment: i edited. but the error remain same

Comment: I can't see your code, but it's quite clear that you din not edit it correctly / not in the proper place etc.